# Join tables without missing data

Tags: sql

I have three tables.

The First table contains my **raw** data and the other two are “**satellite**” tables. All three of them have the same key **acc_num**.

**Raw data table columns:**

- Acc_num
- Date
- Campaign

**Satellite1 columns:**

- Sat_id
- Sat_date
- Acc_num

**Satellite2 columns:**

- Sat_id
- Tracking date
- Acc_num

I want to create one SQL base on acc_num that gives me all the acc_num that exists in satellite1 and satellite2. If there is no data in one of the sat tables then I should get null.

**For example:**

In the raw table I will have: acc_num = 1, acc_num = 2, acc_num = 3, acc_num = 4

In satellite1 I will have data for: acc_num = 1 and acc_num = 2

In satellite2 I will have data for: acc_num = 3 and acc_num = 4

So the output will be:

| Acc_num | Satellite1.Sat_date | Satellite2.Tracking date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/16/2020 | null |
| 2 | 4/16/2021 | null |
| 3 | null | x1 |
| 4 | null | x2 |

Hope I am clear

Thank you

Comment: This  is a simple JOIN.

Comment: simple left join, to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Raw_table_name.Acc_num,
  Satellite1.Sat_date,
  Satellite2.Tracking_date
FROM
  Raw_table_name
  JOIN Satellite1 ON Raw_table_name.Acc_num = Satillite1.Acc_num
  JOIN Satellite2 ON Satellite2.Acc_num = Satellite1.Acc_num
```

From the above statement you are selecting the required columns for the output from the main raw_data table by joining the sub tables on that matching columns

Comment: Thank you venkatesh for your help. Unfortunately that not working from me.

Comment: @angus try using left join or inner join

Comment: Left join did the job. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
Raw_table_name.Acc_num,
Satellite1.Sat_date,
Satellite2.Tracking_date
FROM
Raw_table_name
LEFT JOIN Satellite1 ON Raw_table_name.Acc_num = Satillite1.Acc_num
LEFT JOIN Satellite2 ON Satellite2.Acc_num = Satellite1.Acc_num

Comment: Thank you teknik. I already got the solution.